# Configure JFROG CLI and Xray through the GitLab pipeline for dotnet project

Tags: .net, gitlab, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I would like to configure build artifacts and dependencies scan for vulnerabilities and license violations for a .NET project through the pipeline. I am new to JFrog Artifactory and Xray and currently my pipeline is failing with error:

> [Error] resolver information is missing within /builds/project-name/.jfrog/projects/dotnet.yaml

I followed this [documentation](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-build-and-publish-a-nuget-project-using-the-jfrog-cli-to-artifactory-and-how-to-scan-it-and-what-to-expect-after-it-is-scanned-by-jfrog-xray/). It's never mentioned that I have to have this file and I can't find how this file should look like in their docs. Did someone else had similar issue?

This is current state of my configuration file for GitLab's pipeline:

```
......
    xray:
      stage: Xray
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
      before_script:
        - PROXY_ADDRESS="${PROXY_ADDRESS}"
        - chmod +x add-proxy.sh
        - ./add-proxy.sh "PROXY_ADDRESS"
        - source /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
      script:
        - apt update && apt upgrade --yes
        - apt install curl --yes
        - curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
        - ./jfrog config add project-name --artifactory-url="${JFROG_FULL_URL}" --user="${JFROG_USER}" --access-token="${JFROG_TOKEN}"
        - ./jfrog config show
        - ./jfrog config use project-name
        - ./jfrog rt dotnet-config
        - ./jfrog rt dotnet restore -s nuget.config --build-name=$CI_JOB_NAME --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
        - ./jfrog rt dotnet pack ./project-name/project-name.csproj --build-name=$CI_JOB_NAME --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
        - ./jfrog rt build-collect-env $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
        - ./jfrog rt build-add-git $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
        - ./jfrog rt build-publish $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
        - ./jfrog rt build-scan $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
```

Error is thrown on this line:

```
- ./jfrog rt dotnet restore -s nuget.config --build-name=$CI_JOB_NAME --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
```

Comment: Can you verify you aren't missing a repository for dependencies resolution?
--repo-resolve

Comment: How can I confirm this ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The `jfrog rt dotnet-config` command is an interactive command by default.

The command creates a project configuration used by the `jfrog rt dotnet` command.

Since you are running it in CI, you may provide the config command your resolution details with flags. See the command help for more info:

```
$ jfrog dotnet-config -h

Name:
  jfrog dotnet-config - Generate dotnet configuration.

Usage:
  jfrog dotnet-config [command options]

Options:
  --global               [Default: false] Set to true if you'd like the configuration to be global (for all projects). Specific projects can override the global configuration.
  --nuget-v2             [Default: false] Set to true if you'd like to use the NuGet V2 protocol when restoring packages from Artifactory.
  --repo-resolve         [Optional] Repository for dependencies resolution.
  --server-id-resolve    [Optional] Artifactory server ID for resolution. The server should configured using the 'jfrog c add' command.
```

P.S:

This blog is a bit outdated, and still suggests using an older version of JFrog CLI.

Since you are configuring a new pipeline, I suggest upgrading to JFrog CLI v2. It requires a bit of modifications to your script, but since v1 hardly gets any updates now, it should be worth the effort.

The installation command should change to `curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh`, which will install the CLI globally, with the new executable name `jf`. This means `./jfrog` in your script should be changed to `jf`.

Dotnet commands were moved to the `jf` namespace (`./jfrog rt dotnet ...` -> `jf dotnet ...`)

All changes are documented [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI#JFrogCLI-JFrogCLIv2).

Comment: Hi Prostagma, thank you for your answer. I already tried to configure in my pipeline JFrog CLI v2 but in a different way and it didn't work. Thanks to your comment I have managed to achieve this.

Regarding my first issue :) I have reconfigured dotnet-config line like this  jf rt dotnet-config --nuget-v2=false --repo-resolve=https://www.nuget.org --server-id-resolve=project-name and now error is thrown: Unable to load the service index for source https://company_artifactory_path/api/nuget/v3/https:/www.nuget.org. [/builds/project-name.sln]

Comment: @MilicaNikolić repo-resolve should be a repository in Artifactory. If you wish to resolve from nuget.org, create a remote repository pointing there. Also try replacing `jf rt dotnet-config ...` -> `jf dotnet-config ...`.

Comment: I have created remote repo as you suggested but now I am getting this error:
[Debug] Sending HTTP GET request to: https://artifactory.company.domain/api/system/version
[Debug] Usage Report: failed while attempting to get Artifactory version:
server response: 404 Not Found
404 page not found
  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://artifactory.company.domain/api/nuget/v3/project-nuget-dev-remote. [/builds/project/Project.sln]

Do you have any idea how to proceed ?